# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.impl.TypesImpl.getType

Tags: jakarta-ee, nullpointerexception, glassfish

I get this error/warning each time I do a deploy of the application. I use netbeans 7.2.1 IDE, Glassfish server 3.1.2 and primefaces 3.3.1. The deploy is successful but I'm curious about the reason why this appears.

```
SEVERE: Exception while visiting java/lang/Object.class of size 1475
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.impl.TypesImpl.getType(TypesImpl.java:78)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.impl.ModelClassVisitor.visit(ModelClassVisitor.java:119)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:171)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:348)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:70)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:307)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:296)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is the same as this known [bug - Glassfish 18513](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18513). I was actually looking this up the other day.

From what I can tell it doesn't cause any issues, but it is unsettling. It does have 26 votes so hopefully it's fixed soon.